# Including null fields when mapping JSON request body to MultiValueMap in HTTP POST request

Tags: spring-boot, http, jpa, post, httprequest

I have the following REST endpoint, which takes in an array of requests and returns a match for each request, through a JPA query for each request

```
@PostMapping(value = "/matchAll", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<?> findMatches(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> input) {
      return someService.findMatches(input);
}
```

MultiValueMap works if all fields are given and not null, but consider the following request

```
"requests": [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "name": "Steph",
        "gender": "F",
        "age": 19
    },
    {
        "name": "Jamie",
        "gender": "M",
        "age": 18
    },

]
```

When this request is received, multivaluemap will generate the following lists:

```
"name": { "John", "Steph", "Jamie" }
"gender" { "F", "M" }
"age" { 25, 19, 18 }
```

Then I will find a match using JPA as follows

```
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(John, F, 25);
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(Steph, M, 19);
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(Jamie, null, 18);
```

This is incorrect, what I want is

```
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(John, null, 25);
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(Steph, F, 19);
findFirstByNameAndGenderAndAge(Jamie, M, 18);
```

When a field is missing/null, the succeeding values will be shifted up because multivaluemap does not consider null values. What can I do to solve this problem?

I use multivaluemap because it is the only solution I found that is compatible with x-www-urlencoded-form.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal kind of. the problem is this feature is part of a microservice network that many services use. we will have to include this logic in all services, but yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution to solve this issue with `MultiValueMap` but I have implemented a workaround for this.

1. The client can pass the "null" string if there is no value available.

[image]

2. Update this "null" string with null in the code.

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/matchAll" , consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> findMatches(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> input) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Input : "+ input);
        final Map<String, List<String>> map = input
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, DemoController::getValue));
        System.out.println(map);
        //TODO: Remaining code
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("fine");
    }

    private static List<String> getValue(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e) {
        final List<String> value = e.getValue();
        final boolean result = Collections.replaceAll(value, "null", null);
        if (result){
            System.out.println("List is updated successfully");
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

3. Output

```
Input : {name=[John, Steph, Jamie], gender=[null, F, M], age=[25, 19, 18]}
List is updated successfully
{gender=[null, F, M], name=[John, Steph, Jamie], age=[25, 19, 18]}
```